# OpsWorks Chef 11.10 undefined method 'property'

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Chef 11.10 ran fine until we resized an instance, now `setup_failed` on boot with log:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `property' for #<Class:0x007f7c97afc100>


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb:22:in `class_from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb:

21:  
22>> property :program_name, String, name_property: true
23:  property :path, String, coerce: proc { |x| x.tr('/', '\\') }
24:  property :args, String
25:  property :root, Symbol,
26:           equal_to: %i(machine user),
27:           default: :machine
28:  
29:  alias_method :program, :path
30:  
31:  action :create do
```

The Berkshelf version is `3.2.0`. I'm unable to SSH into the instance to get detailed logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a cookbook that requires a newer version of Chef. Specifically that cookbook requires Chef 12.5 or newer I think.

Comment: Is there anyway to keep using 11.10?

Comment: Sure, use an older version of the cookbook that is compatible with Chef 11.